# CSS: another button in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

These are my code:

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
}

li a{
    display:block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active { 
    background-color: #111;
}   

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
    background: dimgrey;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body> 
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html" target="_parent">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="log-in.html" target="_parent">Sign In/Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#order">Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="movies.html" target="_parent">More Movies</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" target="_parent">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

I want to add another button that has different a `background-color` and possible will be put in the very right side which will be separate to the other buttons. I don't have any idea of how to separate it from other buttons so I just tried changing its background. I tried making another class because the other button will not be clickable, just for display, and also doesn't have hovered effect. But it still won't work. Can you give me some suggestions please?

Comment: Might you privide a feedle, so we can act directly on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
}

li a{
    display:block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active { 
    background-color: #111;
}   

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
    background: dimgrey;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.special {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body> 
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html" target="_parent">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="log-in.html" target="_parent">Sign In/Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#order">Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="movies.html" target="_parent">More Movies</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" target="_parent">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="special"><a>special</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

This is my solution, give the special li a class, and set the float right

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Admin Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Page1</title>
    <style> ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a{
        display:block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }
    button{
        float: right;
        background-color: #2e6aab;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 50px;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #111;
        display:block;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    body {
        background: dimgrey;
        font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    body :-moz-placeholder {
        font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        opacity: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    body ::-moz-placeholder {
        font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        opacity: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    body :-ms-input-placeholder {
        font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" target="_parent">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="log-in.html" target="_parent">Sign In/Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#order">Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="movies.html" target="_parent">More Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" target="_parent">Contact</a></li>
    <li><button>AnotherBtn</button></li>

</ul>
</html>
```